# Django - serving an ical file

Tags: django, icalendar

I'm server an icalender file through django_ical. Problem is that the file is named download.ics. I'm trying to change this to MyCalender.ics. If found this old snippet. I would prefer using django_ical, because it ingerates nicely with django syndication.

```
cal = vobject.iCalendar()
cal.add('method').value = 'PUBLISH'  # IE/Outlook needs this
for event in event_list:
     vevent = cal.add('vevent')
icalstream = cal.serialize()
response = HttpResponse(icalstream, mimetype='text/calendar')
response['Filename'] = 'filename.ics'  # IE needs this
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=filename.ics'
```

Comment: could you post your django_ical code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [`django_ical`](https://django-ics.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) the `ICalFeed` is inherited from `django.contrib.syndication.views.Feed`

In your app you inherit from `ICalFeed` to provide `items`, `item_title` and other methods that generate data for ics file.

You can override the `__call__` method. The call to `super` will return you `HttpResponse` and you will add custom headers to it.

The code will be something like:

```
class EventFeed(ICalFeed):
    """
    A simple event calender
    """
    product_id = '-//example.com//Example//EN'
    timezone = 'UTC'

    def items(self):
        return Event.objects.all().order_by('-start_datetime')

    # your other fields

    def __call__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(EventFeed, self).__call__(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if response.mimetype == 'text/calendar':
            response['Filename'] = 'filename.ics'  # IE needs this
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=filename.ics'
        return response
```

This code is not tested, so there might be some typos. Also you need to catch if there were errors in call to `super`. I do it by `response.mimetype == 'text/calendar'` but maybe there is a better way to do it

Comment: I had the same solution. Thanks.